How does the options markets affect the stock market more significantly?
I was watching a vertasium video on the black scholes equations, in the video they mentioned that during the game stop surge, the reason why retail traders could bid the price of the STOCK higher was because they bought stock options . They said that 1 dollar could only buy 1 dollar worth of stock so buying the stock itself wouldn't be able to push the price enough, however, with 1 dollar you could buy options that could affect 10 or potentially 20 dollars worth of the underlying stock, therefore there is natural leverage in those securities.
How does this make sense?

Are you sure you didn't mishear? The option could be affected 10x or 20x times more than the underlying stock (i.e. if the underlying stock goes up 1% an option could go up 10% or  20%). I don't see how buying options could enact leverage on the underlying stock/

The option's price will move more percentagewise than the stock.  However, in a gamma squeeze, share price will move more in terms of total dollars.

When a market maker sells calls, they hedge these calls by buying underlying shares because if the stock rises, they must deliver stock to option buyers.
The number of shares needed is based on the delta of the call.  The more call options market makers sell, the more shares they need to buy. Since shares are far more expensive than an option, "1 dollar spent on an option could affect 10 or 20 dollars worth of the underlying stock'.
These share purchases drive share price higher, increasing the delta of the options. That in turn forces market makers to buy even more stock to manage risk their risk (higher delta).  It becomes a feedback loop.  Buy more shares, call delta increases resulting in more shares needed.   If this becomes extreme, it's called a gamma squeeze.
